# Generate SVG graphic using values from MySQL database table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, graphics, svg

i'm trying to echo this

```
echo $row['positionX'] . " " . $row['positionY'];
```

as polygone points in a svg graphic code snippet

```
<polyline points = "...HERE..." fill = "none" stroke = "blue" stroke-width = "3"/>
```

how do i that?
thanks

Comment: `"...HERE..."` = `"<?php echo $row['positionX'] . " " . $row['positionY'] ;?>"`

Comment: yeah working, and ive changed to <circle instead of polygone to fetch all points... thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways, depending on requirements or coding style:-

1. `$.getJSON(....)` jQuery method where the server `echo json_decode($row);`, then dynamically draw the polyline from JSON data (eg: RaphaelJS or SnapSVG saves you a bit of coding)
2. `echo "<polyline points=\"$row['positionX'],$row['positionX']\" \/>";`

For Single Page Application, use #1 since it is an AJAX call.

For a one time page load, #2 coding is simple enough.

Note:  too many `<?php echo` in a HTML is hard to debug, also recommend [moustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) templating to help readability and code simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<polyline points = "<?php echo $row['positionX'] . " " . $row['positionY']; ?>" fill = "none" stroke = "blue" stroke-width = "3"/>
```